# Listening to webview actions to implement paystack in RN

Tags: react-native, webview, paystack

I am trying to run paystack inside a webview however it has a button called cancel payment that doesn't do anything.  I am told that the button runs a function called onClose that runs window.close but since its in a webview it doesn't work.

Now I am trying to hook into that function and ideally make a navigation action but for now just a console.log or alert would be good enough.

This is what the webview looks like now

```
<WebView 
      source={{ uri: authorization_url }}
      onNavigationStateChange={() => console.log('navstate changed')}
      cacheEnabled={false}
      cacheMode={'LOAD_NO_CACHE'}
      onMessage={(e) => {
          console.log('pressed')
          JSON.parse(e.nativeEvent?.data);
      }}
      onClose={() => {
        console.log('on close')
        navigation.navigate(callBackRoute)
      }}
    />
```

I thought of adding `injectedJavaScript` prop but i cant work out what to put in it, I've tried a bunch of things so far without any success.

Below is link to payfast documentation
https://paystack.com/docs/guides/using_the_paystack_checkout_in_a_mobile_webview/

Update:  I got this working with a timeout hack, would definitely prefer to find a way to remove the timeout and just make it work correctly but the following code is functional

```
const js = `
      setTimeout(function() {
      var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button')
      buttons.forEach((button) => {
        if(button.innerHTML.includes('Cancel Payment')) {
          button.addEventListener("click", function() {  
              var resp = {event:'cancelled'};
              window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(resp))
              });
        }
      })
    }, 3000);
      true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
    `
```

and

```
const onNavigationStateChange = state => {
    const { url } = state;
    webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(js)
    // other navigationStateChangeCode
  }
```

Comment: Put in injectedJavaScript script that find a button and add event listener, witch will call onMessage via window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage()

Comment: this is what im trying to do, how do i find the button though?

Comment: please ,paste here in comments html markup of button

Comment: i dont have it but ill add the documentation to the question

Comment: From docmentation - The workaround is to have your WebView listen for when the URL has been redirected to  https://standard.paystack.co/close

Comment: to my prev comment https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

Comment: unfortuanately that doesnt work, window.close isnt caught by the onNavigationStateChange since its ignored

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238151/discussion-between-quintis-and-adam-katz).

Comment: Did you try to use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect DOM changes? If it supports, you can detect the button when it comes in the DOM. [Somebody tried before but did not succeed.](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1292)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the window.onload event which is fired once the document has finished loading, instead of setting a timeout.

```js
function onButtonClick() {
  var resp = {event:'cancelled'};
  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(resp))
}

window.onload = function() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  buttons.forEach((button) => {
    if(button.innerHTML.includes('Cancel Payment')) {
      button.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: didnt work :(  The website starts in a loading state so im assuming it has something to do with that.

Comment: Hello, were you able to resolve this without using setTimeout?

Comment: The problem with settimeout is what if the page delays for more than the setTimeout. Is there a way to detect when the page is fully loaded with css files and all that? I can see that the page uses loading state and the script fires at this time which fails to find any html element because there was none. The settimeout helps to delay the script from running instantly. This works but what if the page takes longer time to load, let say, longer than 4 seconds.