# Cancel Payment Button in paystack not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, react-native-webview, paystack

I am implementing payment gateway with `paystack` for the first time and I really don't want to use third party packages for `paystack`. It is a React Native application. I wanted to implement it using `react native webview`. It is working so far but I can't seem to get the cancel button to work. This is because the button is not responding when clicked. If the button responded and invoked the paystack `onClose` URL `https://standard.paystack.co/close`, I would have simply checked for it and close the webview state.

So, how do I handle this? The button can't be there without doing anything. Can I use javascript and hide it and create my own custom button that actually works on click?: Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
const { url } = value
if (!url) return;
webView.current.injectJavaScript(handleCancle)

const customUrl = url.split('?');
const getCallBackURL = customUrl[0];
const queryStr = customUrl[1]
if(getCallBackURL == callback_url){
    setPaymentState(false);
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/payverify/?${queryStr}`);

        if(res?.data?.status == 'success'){
            
            const  payMentData = res?.data

             navigation.navigate('ThankyouPage', {payMentData})
        }
    } catch (error) {
        
    }
}
```

The code that tried listening to button click but not working:

```
const handleCancle = `
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

   buttons.forEach((button)=>{
    if(button.innerHTML.includes('Cancel Payment')){
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {  
            console.log('it has happened')
            var resp = {event:'cancelled'};
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(resp))
                
            });
    }
    })
    }
  `
```

The webview:

```
 {
isPaymentSuccess && paymentState &&
<WebView 
javaScriptEnabled={true}
source={{ uri: paymentData }}
style={{ marginTop: 50 }}
onNavigationStateChange={ handleNav }
cacheEnabled={false}
cacheMode={'LOAD_NO_CACHE'}
ref={webView}


onMessage={(e) => {
    console.log('pressed')
    console.log(e.nativeEvent?.data)
 }}

 />
}
```

The error so far: No error. No response when the cancel button is clicked!

Answer (score 1):

Paystack is posting messages when user click 'Cancel Payment'.

```
  parent?.postMessage('close', '*'); // for backward compatibility
  parent?.postMessage({ event: 'close' }, '*');
```

To catch you can inject listener:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    if (event.data.event === 'close') {
        window.location.href = 'https://xyz.cancelled.cxz/feedback';
    }
},false);
```

Answer (score 1):

There has been an update on Paystack, Send a cancel_action in the metadata when you initialize the payment and you should be able to check if URL === cancel_url

https://paystack.com/docs/payments/metadata/#cancel-action

```
"metadata": {
    "cancel_action": "https://your-cancel-url.com"
}
```

With this, you don't need to loop through all the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I drew inspiration from this answer here [Listening to webview actions to implement paystack in RN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573629/listening-to-webview-actions-to-implement-paystack-in-rn).

However, the code didnt work. I think webview wasn't working with `document.getElementByTagName`. Unfortunately, paystack doesnt have a classname for button elements. I decided to use `span` which wrapped the 'cancel text. `Span` elements have a class called `text`. I also used for loop as `includes` method didnt work.
This is the code:

```
const handleCancleScript = `

  setTimeout(function() {
    const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("text")

    for(let button of buttons){
    
       const resp = button.textContent
       if(resp == "Cancel Payment"){
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {  
            var response = {event:'cancelled'};
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(response))
            });
        
       }
       
    }
  
 }, 3000);
  true; 
`
```

The problem now is removing the `setTimeOut`